# Invalid results from HBase Bytes.toString(byte[] b) in Jython

Tags: java, jython, hbase

Wondering what I'm doing wrong here.  Using Jython 2.2.1 on Java 1.5 with Hbase 0.90.  Can't get [Bytes.toString(byte[] b)](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/Bytes.html#toString%28byte%5B%5D%29) to work.  It returns what looks like an address.  But when I use the overloaded [Bytes.toString(byte[] b, int off, int len)](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/Bytes.html#toString%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29), it returns the proper result.

```
g = Get(Bytes.toBytes(id))
res = self.table.get(g)

t = res.getValue(Bytes.toBytes('stuff'), Bytes.toBytes('t'))
print Bytes.toString(t)              // returns stuff like '[B@12121212'
print Bytes.toString(t, 0, len(t))   // returns the string properly
```

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong.  I'm running Jython 2.7 on Java 1.8 and HBase 1.2.4 and am encountering the exact same behavior.  Here is what seems to be happening:  Java supports multiple methods by the same name that accept different sets of parameters, and thus Jython internally has to disambiguate between multiple methods by the same name that accept different parameters.  The Byte[] array that is being converted to a string is represented as a Python array or some subclass thereof, which has a toString( ) method that accepts one parameter (self).  The 'Bytes' object, being a subclass of this, has both the Python array.toString(self) method and the Java .toString(final [] byte b) and .toString(final [] byte b, int off, int len) methods.

It must be that the way the Bytes object is constructed causes Python's .toString(self) to supersede Java's .toString(final [] byte b) but the other method still works because there is no Python .toString( ) method with three parameters to supersede the other Java .toString( ).  (See https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/array.html?highlight=tostring#array.array.tostring)

**Solution:**  A modified import with a few extra lines of code fixes this.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes as BrokenBytes
class Bytes(BrokenBytes):
    @staticmethod
    def toString( x ): return( BrokenBytes.toString( x, 0, len( x ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  There has to be something more to what you are doing than what you have posted.  The first overload of toString calls the second.  Here is the source code (from HBase 0.90.3):

```
  /**
   * @param b Presumed UTF-8 encoded byte array.
   * @return String made from <code>b</code>
   */
  public static String toString(final byte [] b) {
    if (b == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return toString(b, 0, b.length);
  }

  /* snip */

  /**
   * This method will convert utf8 encoded bytes into a string. If
   * an UnsupportedEncodingException occurs, this method will eat it
   * and return null instead.
   *
   * @param b Presumed UTF-8 encoded byte array.
   * @param off offset into array
   * @param len length of utf-8 sequence
   * @return String made from <code>b</code> or null
   */
  public static String toString(final byte [] b, int off, int len) {
    if (b == null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (len == 0) {
      return "";
    }
    try {
      return new String(b, off, len, HConstants.UTF8_ENCODING);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      LOG.error("UTF-8 not supported?", e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Chris.  Maybe it's possible Jython is doing something funky with the byte[] before it goes through Bytes.toString(byte[])?  I can't figure this out but there's nothing weird I'm doing to produce this behavior.